# Is [internet] synonym with [online-interaction]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As of now, there is only three questions for [internet](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)

[Do studies about the internet's negativity exists?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/do-studies-about-the-internets-negativity-exists)

[How can I politely tell a defensive Stack Exchange user to use proper punctuation?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-can-i-politely-tell-a-defensive-stack-exchange-user-to-use-proper-punctuatio)

[How do I indicate sarcasm/irony online?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/161/how-do-i-indicate-sarcasm-irony-online)

On the last two, [internet](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) is used together with [online-interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-interaction).

I think the use of both is excessive, and I can't find why we should keep [internet](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) separate. It does not seem a broader term than [online-interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-interaction).

Comment: Just to be clear, which tag do you propose should be the "parent tag"? The synonym tag would automatically redirect to the parent tag.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes.

Let's make [internet](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet) a synonym of [online-interaction](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-interaction) and not just remove it, since it's bound to be recreated otherwise.

If you have earned the required privilege (at least a net score of 5 on the tag), [you can vote for it](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/online-interaction/synonyms).

Comment: Upvote in here if you all agree that "online interaction" should remain as the main tag, and "internet" should automatically change into the main tag. https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/online-interaction/synonyms